# Get inner value of the rendering parameter

Tags: presentation

For the rendering parameters, I have a droplist which consists of the friendly name of the `CSS-class` which further consists of a value field for the actual `CSS-class`.

In my view when I try to retrieve the rendering parameter, I am always getting a friendly name and not the actual value:

```
var parameter = RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.Parameters["Background"];

<div class="@parameter">
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I understand, you're using field of a `Droplist` type. `Droplist` fields always store their values as the name of the items.

What you may want instead is a `Droplink` field. In the frontend value selector they look the same, but in the background they store item ID instead of item name.

Answer (score 3):

You should use Droplink (as @Marek mentioned above) and extract you parameter value like:

```
var selectedItemId = RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.Parameters["Background"];
var selectedItem = RenderingContext.Current.ContextItem.Database.GetItem(ID.Parse(Guid.Parse(selectedItemId)));
    var parameter = selectedItem["Value"];
```

or the easiest way if you have Glass Mapper in your project:

```
var parameter = GetRenderingParameters<YourRpModel>().Value;
```